# OpenLayers. How to create route to the predefiened points?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I am new in programming and think that here you can help me...

I have to create web-app where user can navigate to predefined points. In other words, first user define his/her own location (example, "Geolocate me") and then choose one of the point from the list. And route should be created automatically between these two points.

Now I only find how to find own location...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the various [online routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers). Many offer a GPX export of the route. OpenLayers is able to display GPX tracks.